# Adding a day in Oracle but losing hour and minute, and format is also changing

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

I have a table `tab1` in which a column `col1` has data type `VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)` and this column has values like '9/27/21 18:05'

I want to add 1 day to this and I am expecting a result like '9/28/21 18:05'

If I do

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

then I get '28-SEP-21 06.24.00.000000000 PM', and if I do

```
TO_DATE(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY'
```

then I get '28-SEP-21'.

Please note in both the above cases format is changing.

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? Anyway... you aren't losing the time; you just need the equivalent `to_char()` to turn the date (or timestamp) back into a string in the right format.

Comment: When you say 'I get'.. what are you printing? A result from sql*plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting your string into a date or timestamp, and adjusting it by a day. Your client then decides how to format that for display, usually using you session setting like `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

If you want to display (or store*) the value in a particular format then you should specify that, with `to_char()`, e.g.:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

```
09/28/0021 18:05
```

or if you want to suppress some leading zeros to match your original string you can toggle those with [the `FM` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY,'FMMM/DD/YYYY HH24:FMMI')
```

```
9/28/21 18:05
```

As you can see in the output of first of those, and as @Aitor mentioned, the year comes out as 0021 rather than 21. That's because you used a four-digit YYYY mask for a 2-digit year value. In the second one the `FM` suppresses that, so it's less obvious. As you don't seem to care about the century it usually doesn't matter whether you use `YY` or `RR` - the exception maybe being if you happen to hit a leap year/day; but it's still better to have the mask match the string, so with `RR`:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(col1,'MM/DD/RR HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY,'FMMM/DD/RR HH24:FMMI')
```

```
9/28/21 18:05
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6aa75d388d05d167dbfaf28fc50e15fc)

* But you should not be storing dates as strings. They should be stored *as dates*, and formatted as strings for display only. You shouldn't really be using 2-digit years any more either.

Comment: the fm  solution  gives output  as '9/28/21 6:05'  instead  of  '9/28/21 06:05'   though  in case  of  '9/28/21 16:05'  it  is  fine.

Comment: @AmitKumarTyagi - if you want hours with leading zero too them put the second FM before that - `'FMMM/DD/RR FMHH24:MI'`

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` values are both binary data types that do **NOT** have a given format; therefore, when you convert a string to a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP` then the format you use is **NOT** stored.

If you want to convert it to a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and then back to a string in the same format then, after adding the interval, you want to use `TO_CHAR` to convert back to a string with the required format.

For example:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(col1, 'MM/DD/RR HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         'MM/DD/RR HH24:MI'
       )
FROM   tab1
```

*Note: If you use `YYYY` in the format model then `21` will be parsed as 21 AD and not as 2021 AD. Instead, you need to use `YY` or `RR` (depending on how you want values from the end of the last century to be handled).*

> Please note in both the above cases format is changing.

The format of your column is not changing, you have converted the strings to `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` which are binary data type and do not have any format.

The user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus or SQL Developer) tries to be helpful and rather than presenting you, the user, with binary data will use its internal rules to format the binary data as something you can read. SQL/Plus and SQL Developer will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter for `DATE` values and the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter for `TIMESTAMP` values. These parameters can be set to different values for each user in each of their sessions so you should not rely on them to be consistent.

If you want a consistent format then wrap the date/timestamp in `TO_CHAR` to apply that consistent format.

Answer (score 1):

You said your column has this: 9/27/21, but you put a mask like YYYY. Be careful with that, because with YYYY, the year will be 21 BC...

Maybe you want RRRR in your date mask. RRRR means 2-digit years in the range 00 to 49 are assumed to be in the current century:

```
select to_char(to_date('9/27/2021 18:05','MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI')+ INTERVAL '1' DAY,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') result 
from dual;
```

Result: 09/28/2021 18:05

I don't know what is your output format, but anyway, if you want your date formatted like VARCHAR, try this. With your column, is something like that

```
select to_char(to_date(col1,'MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI') + 1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') result 
from your_table;
```

Also you can use, instead of INTERVATL '1' DAY, a simple +1

Comment: Good point about YYYY, although the OP doesn't seem to want to see the century. You've lost the `to_date(` from your second query though.